# How to access the output of gcloud build steps in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm following the tutorial at https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/orchestrating-pytorch-ml-workflows-vertex-ai-pipelines?hl=en .

They are using the python client to create build steps. In my case that looks like

```
import logging
from google.cloud.devtools import cloudbuild_v1 as cloudbuild
from google.protobuf.duration_pb2 import Duration    

# Deploy the serving container to cloud run
build = cloudbuild.Build()
build.steps = [
    {
        "name": "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk",
        "entrypoint": "gcloud",
        "args": [
            "run", "deploy", service_name,
            "--image", image_uri,
            "--region", serving_location,
            "--cpu", serving_cpu,
            "--min-instances", serving_min_instances,
            "--max-instances", serving_max_instances,
            "--memory", serving_memory,
            serving_authentication,
        ],
    },
    {
        "name": "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk",
        "entrypoint": "/bin/bash",
        "args": [
            "gcloud", "run", "services", "describe", service_name,
            "--platform", "managed",
            "--region", serving_location,
            "--format", "json",
            " > $$BUILDER_OUTPUT/output"
        ]
    }
]
# Override default timeout of 10min.
timeout = Duration()
timeout.seconds = 7200
build.timeout = timeout
operation = build_client.create_build(project_id=project, build=build)

result = operation.result(timeout=7200)
logging.info("RESULT: %s", result.results)
```

I would like to retrieve the URL of the deployed service in step one to use it in the python code. So in step two I'm calling `gcloud run services describe` and try to write output into `$BUILDER_OUTPUT/output`. As I understand it, this should pipe the output from the build step into the field `result.results.build_step_outputs`, which I could access from the python code, see

- https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudbuild/latest/google.cloud.devtools.cloudbuild_v1.types.Results
- https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#results

I also found an example making use of `$BUILDER_OUTPUT/output` at https://atamel.dev/posts/2022/10-17_executing_commands_from_workflows/.

However then running the steps above I get the error message

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 generic::invalid_argument: invalid value for 'build.substitutions': key in the template "BUILDER_OUTPUT" is not a valid built-in substitution
```

So what am I doing wrong here? And is there (maybe another) way to retrieve the URL of the service deployed in step one, so I can use it inside the python code?

Comment: Have you seen the  list of valid built-in substitutions in the Cloud Build [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values)

Answer (score 2):

After a search on github I finally found a workaround for the issue (see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/workflows-demos/issues/73) . Instead of using the environment variable `$BUILDER_OUTPUT` as suggested in the documentation one can pipe the output directly into `/builder/outputs/output`. Then one can extract the output in python from `result.results.build_step_outputs`. So I changed my code to

```
build.steps = [
    ...
    {
        "name": "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk",
        "entrypoint": "/bin/bash",
        "args": [
            "-c", "gcloud run services describe " + service_name +
            " --platform managed" +
            " --region " + serving_location +
            " --format 'value(status.url)'" +
            " > /builder/outputs/output"
        ]
    }
]
# Override default timeout of 10min.
timeout = Duration()
timeout.seconds = 7200
build.timeout = timeout

operation = build_client.create_build(project_id=project, build=build)

result = operation.result(timeout=7200)
url = result.results.build_step_outputs[1].decode('utf-8').strip()
```

It seems the environment variable `$BUILDER_OUTPUT` simply  isn't set anymore. At least it isn't mentioned on https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values . It is also telling that the in the github issue mentioned above the comment says:

```
# TODO: Should use $BUILDER_OUTPUT for "/builder/ouputs", but couldn't get substitution to work
```

So maybe someone should open a github issue on this.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your Cloud Build step. You are using a linux output redirect, in a args format

If you look at the Mete sample, it use the bash command format. So, update your step like that

```
    {
        "name": "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk",
        "entrypoint": "/bin/bash",
        "args": [
            "-c", "gcloud run services describe" + service_name +
            "--platform managed --region" + serving_location +
            "--format json > $$BUILDER_OUTPUT/output"
        ]
    }
```

*I'm not python expert, maybe my line returns are wrong*

Comment: I tried that, but it gave me the same error: `details = "generic::invalid_argument: invalid value for 'build.substitutions': key in the template "BUILDER_OUTPUT" is not a valid built-in substitution"` Your point about the redirect might be right, but it seems to fail earlier, because the "BUILDER_OUTPUT" variable seems to be "invalid".